# Center a span and image verticallly inside a div

Tags: html, css

How can I center vertically the span and the image here?

```
<div id="foo">
  <span>Im great</span>
  <image src="">
</div>


div {
  height:350px; 
  background:yellow;
}
div span{
  line-height: 350px;
  background: red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LlCyj)

When I remove the image the span is centered, but if I add the image the span is not centered any more..why?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work

```
<div id="foo">
<span style="vertical-align:middle;">Im great</span>
<image style="vertical-align:middle;" src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcROD-0j3FBYzU2dxJMpps3ZWiYl0dKoEdt1EE4c5zVHtPfhyw_59q4WEX2S">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a div and then use the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <span>Im great</span>
      <image src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#foo{
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And if you want fully centered you can add: `left: 0`, `right: 0` .

Answer (score 0):

http://cdpn.io/yvanH

adding a `<br />` tag after span lets the img flow below the span